Ignore characters in a string to make an R date
Im trying to get the date from a string such as: "ID0123122021".
Where the first two digits are an id, then the month then the year.
So it would be equivalent to "IDnnnnmmyyyy" and the actual date would be 12-2021.
I want to extract the final date. I have tried:
as.Date("ID0123122021", format = "ID%nnnn%m%Y")

As expected it returns NA, since %n, does not exist (https://www.statology.org/r-date-format/). I also tried
as.Date("ID0123122021", format = "ID0123%m%Y")

Which does not work either and would not be particularly useful since the ID may change.
Is there any way to define a format with characters to ignore? Something like format = %iiiiii%m%Y, Where the %i flag would mean ignore this character when building the date?
Thanks!

Add a regular expression to the mix to extract that relevant part first:
date_str <- "ID0123122021"
# extract last 6 digits if those are preceded by IDxxxx
stringr::str_extract(date_str, "(?<=ID\\d{4})\\d{6}$") |> lubridate::my()
#> [1] "2021-12-01"

Created on 2024-04-23 with reprex v2.1.0

You could extract the date element, insert the 1st of the month, then convert to a date object.
Then you could format as you like.
library(stringr)
library(lubridate)

x <- str_sub("ID0123122021", 7, 12) |> str_c("01") |> myd()
x
#> [1] "2021-12-01"

format(x, "%Y %b")
#> [1] "2021 Dec"

Created on 2024-04-23 with reprex v2.1.0

You can use my() and skip concatenating the day.

Thanks. Hadn't spotted the existence of that one :)

A solution based on regex only and backreference is this:
data.frame(strings) %>%
  mutate(strings_date = str_replace(strings, ".*(.{2})(.{4})$", "\\1-\\2")) 
        strings strings_date
1  ID0123122021      12-2021
2 ID45637062019      06-2019

How this works:

.*: after any number and kind of characters...
(.{2}): ...capture and match exactly the next 2 characters, ...
(.{4})$: ... and, immediately thereafter, capture and match the next 4 characters iff they are immediately followed by the string-end anchor $

The backreferences \\1 and \\2 used in the replacement clause serve to recollect the first and, respectively, second capture group, while the - character is inserted between them.
Data:
strings <- c("ID0123122021", "ID45637062019")

